# Deleting CoreData Item which is also an @ObservedObject in DetailView causing App Crash in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, observedobject

I am currently working with `SwiftUI` and `CoreData`.

***Situation:*** I have a `User Detail View` with a `Delete Button`. When pressed, the **Core Data Entry of the User is getting deleted** and the App Navigation goes back to the Root Navigation View, which is a List of all Users.

***Problem:*** Every Time the `Delete Button` is clicked the **App crashes** with the following `Error Message`:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[User timeCreated]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2802ffa40'

***My Guess:*** I guess the Problem has something to do with the Fact, that I use a `@ObservedObject Property Wrapper` for the `User Object` *(look Code below)*. This is also updating on Delete which obviously causes some Problems.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct UserView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \User, ascending: false)], animation: .default) private var users: FetchedResults<User>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    NavigationLink(destination: UserDetailView(user: user)) {
                        Text(user.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @ObservedObject var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { deleteUser() }) {
            Text("Delete")
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteUser() {
        context.delete(user)
            
        do {
            try context.save()
            
            // Navigate Back to List View
            self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error deleting Item from Core Data: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

***Question:*** **How can I delete the User and return to the Root List View without an App Crash?** *(**Note:** Obviously the most easiest Solution would be to make user a normal Property, however, I need the automatic Update Behaviour since there is also a Update User View which may change some of the Content)*

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the issue is in provided code... but try the following (not tested - just idea - defer deleting):

```
private func deleteUser() {
    mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      context.delete(user)
      do {
        try context.save()
      } catch let error as NSError {
          print("Error deleting User from Core Data: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, however the App is still crashing. Do you have another Idea?

Comment: Well... then I think the reason is not in this code. Could you give access to a project or prepare small reproducible demo?

Comment: If this help I can do so. However, Could't the Error be, that in the Moment u delete the User, the ObservedObject Property tries to Update and produces an App Crash bc. the corresponding CoreData Entry was deleted?

Comment: Maybe if you have directly binding to its properties somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I updated the Question above with the full Code for this. Can you spot any Error?

Comment: I've just created simple CoreData project and used your code instead of automatically generated - crash is not reproduced. Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226060/discussion-between-christophriepe-and-asperi).